# Using devise/cancan in several rails application with central authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, authorization, cancan

I need to have single-sign-on and central authentication for 3 of my customer projects(separated rails application under different subdomains). And also I need to manage authorizations with several roles.

This is the first time I am going to manage a SSO, I see that it looks possible to use [ruby-cas-server](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-server)/[ruby-cas-client](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client-rails) with devise to achieve central authentication & SSO. And I am thinking to manage authorizations with roles using CanCan.

The landscope I am thinking will be: there will be a central rails app as the User management, administrator will CRUD users and manage authorizations there. CAS server will do the authentication against the DB of the central user management system. Satellite rails applications will use CAS server for authentication.

I want to ask, is this possible to get the authorization info in the satellite system using CanCan? Is there anyone who've done that? and Is there any better/easier solution to achieved all this?

Thanks a lot.